# Library to interact with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Could you recommend a JavaScript library or jQuery plugin that facilitates interaction with [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

I am mainly interested in bar, pie and line charts.

Ideally I'd like to consume data from html tables or JSON.

Note that I am not talking about the [chart image API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search lead me to:

http://www.ivellios.toron.pl/technikalia/2010/06/22/gvchart-plugin-jquery-with-google-charts/

Demo: http://www.ivellios.toron.pl/technikalia/demos/gvChart/